# Twilio Studio and fixed length recording

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to build an flow in Twilio Studio using voice print identification. To allow that, I need to record a fixed 5 second audio sequence.

The Twilio Studio Record Widget only turns recording on or off - you can't record a fixed length of audio.

I've been exploring using a Twilio Function to use the TwiML Record verb and return that, but I can't work out a way to get the recordingStatusCallback event to return control to the Studio flow.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) 
{ let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse(); 
  twiml.record({ maxLength: 5, timeout: 0, trim: "do-not-trim"}); 
  callback(null, twiml); 
};
```

Clearly I need to include a *recordingStatusCallback*, but where to? It can't return to the Success outcome of the calling Function in the Flow, as that's what returns the TwiML that's generated here.

What I want is to have the RecordingUrl of the recording available in the Flow environment.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi Dave, it would help us if you added some code to show us what you tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: Edited to add the Function code

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the short answer is - you can't. But then, you don't really want to.

The TwiML Record verb starts a different thread to process the audio while it returns control via the Action URL. So you **have** to handle the recordingStatusCallback event somewhere else.

I ended up by pointing the callback at another Twilio Function. That does the necessary processing (in my case, using the recording for a voiceprint enrollment).